# How to convert an ordered dict into a pandas dataframe with each key value ('label') for each column

Tags: pandas, ordereddict

How to convert an ordered dict into a pandas dataframe with each key ('label') for each column.

````
```OderedDict = [OrderedDict([('dataCells',
               [OrderedDict([('label', 'BT Ltd'),
                             ('value', '00120000000I3eZAAS')]),
                OrderedDict([('label',
                              'BP | Alert generated for Rejected FileAct message in GTE'),
                             ('value', '5007R00002otgJRQAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '12/27/2020 1:57 AM'),
                             ('value', '2020-12-27T06:57:16Z')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '52'), ('value', 52)]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'false'), ('value', False)]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'true'), ('value', True)]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '00120000000I3eZ'),
                             ('value', '00120000000I3eZAAS')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'GTE'),
                             ('value', 'GTE')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'FM'),
                             ('value', 'FM')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'Cust'), ('value', 'Cust')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'Incident'),
                             ('value', 'Incident')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '07370371'),
                             ('value', '5007R00002otgJRQAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '5007R00002otgJR'),
                             ('value', '5007R00002otgJRQAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '00120000000I3eZ'),
                             ('value', '00120000000I3eZAAS')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'BT UK'),
                             ('value', 'a93w000000001NSAAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'Amanda Pandas'),
                             ('value', '0052X000008LWapQAG')])])]),```
````

## convert to pandas data frame

`df = pd.DataFrame(report_results['factMap']['T!T']['rows'] )`

#use pd.Series to create columns in dataframe

`df = df.dataCells.apply(pd.Series)`

I have attempted the above but I end up with columns of ordered dicts ({'label': 'GTE', 'value': 'GTE'})
How would I just get the label value 'GTE'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the data frame, expand the `list` then convert the `dict` to columns

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = [OrderedDict([('dataCells',
               [OrderedDict([('label', 'BT Ltd'),
                             ('value', '00120000000I3eZAAS')]),
                OrderedDict([('label',
                              'BP | Alert generated for Rejected FileAct message in GTE'),
                             ('value', '5007R00002otgJRQAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '12/27/2020 1:57 AM'),
                             ('value', '2020-12-27T06:57:16Z')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '52'), ('value', 52)]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'false'), ('value', False)]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'true'), ('value', True)]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '00120000000I3eZ'),
                             ('value', '00120000000I3eZAAS')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'GTE'),
                             ('value', 'GTE')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'FM'),
                             ('value', 'FM')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'Cust'), ('value', 'Cust')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'Incident'),
                             ('value', 'Incident')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '07370371'),
                             ('value', '5007R00002otgJRQAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '5007R00002otgJR'),
                             ('value', '5007R00002otgJRQAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', '00120000000I3eZ'),
                             ('value', '00120000000I3eZAAS')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'BT UK'),
                             ('value', 'a93w000000001NSAAY')]),
                OrderedDict([('label', 'Amanda Pandas'),
                             ('value', '0052X000008LWapQAG')])])])]

# create DF,  expand list, convert dict to columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode("dataCells")["dataCells"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
```

### output

```
                                                    label                 value
                                                   BT Ltd    00120000000I3eZAAS
 BP | Alert generated for Rejected FileAct message in GTE    5007R00002otgJRQAY
                                       12/27/2020 1:57 AM  2020-12-27T06:57:16Z
                                                       52                    52
                                                    false                 False
                                                     true                  True
                                          00120000000I3eZ    00120000000I3eZAAS
                                                      GTE                   GTE
                                                       FM                    FM
                                                     Cust                  Cust
                                                 Incident              Incident
                                                 07370371    5007R00002otgJRQAY
                                          5007R00002otgJR    5007R00002otgJRQAY
                                          00120000000I3eZ    00120000000I3eZAAS
                                                    BT UK    a93w000000001NSAAY
                                            Amanda Pandas    0052X000008LWapQAG
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What if I wanted to put each key in it's own column? ```df[0] = 'BT Ltd', df[1] = 'BP | Alert generated for Rejected FileAct message in GTE' , df[2] = '12/27/2020 1:57 AM'``` , etc.

Comment: `df.set_index("label").T` it's a simple transpose of an index